# Sending immediate response and detailed message in DialogFlow

Tags: facebook-messenger, dialogflow-es

I have a requirement of sending two messages from my chatbot. The first message will be send immediately as a response like "please wait for a moment" and the second one will be sending after an API call.

I'm using Dialogflow with Facebook messenger. Is it possible in Dialogflow send an immediate message and later send a detailed one?

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't send two responses asynchronously. You could show two simple responses but those would be sent at the same time.

```
app.ask(app.buildRichResponse()
   .addSimpleResponse('This is the first')
   .addSimpleResponse('and this is the second')
);
```

[image]

Comment: The first one I want to send immediately then i want to process the request and send the second message with detailed response.

Comment: It is not possible, you have to send all the response at once.

Comment: my use case is obvious sometimes we need to send an immediate response and later we can give a complete one right?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know a way to give two responses to the user at different times, but as an alternative, you can give a default response to the user along with the fulfillment response in case something goes wrong on the server side like

Bot: Something went wrong.. please check your internet connection or try again after some time.